# PostgreSQL AVG returns trailing zeros

Tags: postgresql

Based on this example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE demo (
  id             CHARACTER(1) NOT NULL,
  value          NUMERIC NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO demo(id, value) VALUES('A','123');
INSERT INTO demo(id, value) VALUES('B','123');
INSERT INTO demo(id, value) VALUES('C','123');

select avg(value) from demo;
select max(value) from demo;
select min(value) from demo;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/rcLK3vKh

I would expect all 3 selects to return `123` but the reality is that the `avg` returns `123.0000000000000000`.

Why this behaviour ocurrs and how can I control it?

Comment: Because `value          NUMERIC` and `NUMERIC` has `scale` per [Numeric type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL).  Either cast: `select '123.0000000000000000'::numeric(6,2); 123.00` or use `round()` from [Math functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html).

Answer (score 1):

As per [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.3.1.1.1), the `AVG` of an "unconstrained `NUMERIC`" is another `NUMERIC`. AFAIK, there are no specific guarantees about the resulting `NUMERIC`'s precision or scale.

You can, of course, manually trim the result. As of PostgreSQL 13 [`TRIM_SCALE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#id-1.5.8.9.6.2.2.26.1.1.1) will do the trick:

```sql
SELECT TRIM_SCALE(AVG(value)) FROM demo;
```

**Working example**: https://dbfiddle.uk/y5-KQFkV